# Mongoose QueryStream.pause() not pausing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

node v.4.2.3 and mongoose v.4.3.6

I have to iterate throught a large (>10k document) collection, and process each document.

Reading the doc about how to handle such iteration, I stumbled upon QueryStream, which, I thought, would solve all of my problem.

```
function progress(total, t, current) {
    process.stdout.clearLine();  // clear current text
    process.stdout.write(Math.round(t / total * 100) + '% ' + t + ' / ' + total + ' ' + current);
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
}

function loadBalance(current, stream) {
    if(!stream.paused && current > 50) {
        log('DEBUG', 'loadBalance', 'pause');
        stream.pause();
    } else if (stream.paused && current < 10) {
        log('DEBUG', 'loadBalance', 'resume');
        stream.resume();
    }
}

var total = 0,
    error = 0,
    goods = 0,
    current = 0;

stream = Raw.find().stream();
stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    heavyProcess(doc, function (err, refined) {
        current = current + 1;
        loadBalance(current, stream);
        printP(total, goods + error, current);
        if(err) {
            error = error + 1;
            current = current - 1;
            loadBalance(current, stream);
        } else {
            new Pure(refined).save(function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    error = error + 1;
                    current = current - 1;
                    loadBalance(current, stream);
                } else {
                    goods = goods + 1;
                    current = current - 1;
                    loadBalance(current, stream);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}).on('error', function (err) {
    log('ERROR', 'stream', err);
}).on('close', function () {
    log('INFO', 'end', goods + ' / ' + total + ' ( ' + (goods/total*100) + '%) OK_');
    log('INFO', 'end', error + ' / ' + total + ' ( ' + (error/total*100) + '%) NOK');
    log('INFO', 'end', (total - goods - error) + ' missing');
});
```

loadBalance does get called, and print it is pausing the stream, but the `'data'` event continue to be fired, even thought `stream.paused` return true.

Did I misunderstood what `pause()` do? Or did I misused QueryStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the real issue was not in the code I posted, but on the Model generation.

I used a new connection, linked raw to it, started to link pure to it too, but at the last moment linked it to the default mongoose connection:

```
db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1/SNCF');          //Creer la connexion a mongodb

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {                                       //Une fois connecte

    raw = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            //...
        },
        {
            strict: true,
            collection: 'Raw'
        }
    );

    Raw = db.model('Raw', raw, 'Raw'); //<--- OK

    pure = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            //...
        },
        {
            strict: true,
            collection: 'Pure'
        }
    );

    Pure = mongoose.model('Pure', pure, 'Pure'); //<-- ERROR
});
```

So no Pure document were saved, and the memory exploded while the CPU were working "normally".

Changing the errored line to `Pure = db.model('Pure', pure, 'Pure');` solved the problem, and I don t even have to pause the stream at all.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose query streams are v1 streams. Referred to in the doc as Node 0.8 ReadStream ( http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream )

That means that the pause event is "advisory" https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_compatibility_with_older_node_js_versions

Advisory here means that after calling pause, some data events will still leak trough.
This has to do with the underlying streaming cache and is the correct stream v1 behavior.
You will have to consume any data events that are produced after calling pause.
This behavior certainly isn't optimal from a developers perspective and that's why it was changed in streams v2 ( https://nodejs.org/en/blog/feature/streams2/ )

Here is a mongoogejs issue relating to v2 query streams, I don't think there are any plans to implement v2 query streams any time soon.
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1907

Quoting form the issue, this might be a work around for your problem:

```
var readStream = (new stream.Readable({ objectMode: true })).wrap(Model.find({}).stream());
```